# No such table android_metadata, what's the problem?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am copying a pre-existing database to `/data/data/packagename/databases` using code learned from [using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

After copying, I recieve the following log message on opening the database:

No such table android_metadata

Do I need to create a table named android_metadata? And what the values do i need insert into this database table

Thanks very much

Comment: If this is resolved please accept the correct answer so that it is no longer flagged as unanswered.

Answer (score 108):

Actually, with a bit more reading, I have discovered that I need to
use the `SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS` flag when calling
`SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase()` - this no longer causes the problem.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS did solve it for me!
Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Use

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
```

or

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Comment: Really simple is just that. Just add write permission to the database and the android automatically add this table.

Comment: Can I use this with READ_ONLY also ?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that for some reason android requires every database to have a table called android_metadata that includes at least one locale. The [reigndesign](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) blog you mentioned tells you how to create the table and prefill it with a locale.

Check if your database contains this table and if the table has some content.

Answer (score 3):

When you copy database from your assets directory for example, then you must have android_metadata table created in it already. This table should have two columns:

```
_id = an integer value
locale = en
```

Answer (score 2):

I am already using as given in that link for a long time..

It works.. Checkout your DB again the table created or not ?

I prefer to install SQLite Manager plugin in firefox for sqlite database operation.. after completing all process as mentioned in the same link..

Checkout http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954.

It contains all database operations.

Answer (score 2):

it might also just be file permissions - the error message is misleading. first you need to find out the user id of the app (this is assuming you have root access):

```
$ adb shell grep <packagename> /data/system/packages.xml
```

output should look like:

```
<package name="com.fsck.k9" codePath="/data/app/com.fsck.k9-1.apk" 
nativeLibraryPath="/data/data/com.fsck.k9/lib" 
flags="0" ft="1306ecac340" it="1306ecac9d2" ut="1306ecac9d2"
version="14001" userId="10002">
```

userId here is 10002.

then fix permissions:

```
$ adb shell chown -R 10002:10002 /data/data/<packagename>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have discovered that this error will happen if I leave an `open transaction` left.

In other words: If you forget to `commit` or `rollback` a transaction, in the next time you enter in your application, this error raises up.