# What is the android_metadata table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to integrate an existing database file into my Android project. 
I follow the instructions on this [blog](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). They write that I have to add a table `android_metadata` with a column called locale and put en_US into it.

I try to figure out what this table is used for. Because my database content is german. Maybe i then should not put en_US into it? Is this required for localisation of the database content or is the table not needed at all?

Comment: In my project I don't have any entry in android_metadata (just an empty table) and it's working fine as well.
Also see the reply on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528489/no-such-table-android-metadata-whats-the-problem, with that option you might not need the table at all anymore (haven't tried it myself though)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the metadata table will be generated automatically. if you have content of german try updating the metadata table 'de_DE'.

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay opening the DB with read-write access then you can let the openDatabase(...) call automatically generate it. For example in Android:

```
SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(m_szMainDBPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

The metadata table is required to hold (as its name suggests) meta information about the application. This table is auto-generated in some cases (since api 4 if i remember correctly) but you may want to add it yourself.