# From where did the file with -journal came and what's its use?

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a db named MY_DATABASE via java code and it worked fine. While running the program, i opened the the file Explorer and found that along with the db that i created i.e; MY_DATABASE there is an extra entry named MY_DATABASE-journal (size: 0) present inside the /data/data/appname/databases folder. I did not created it, then from where did it came and what is its use?

Thanks,
Bunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite uses an additional file for the rollback journal.  You can read an explanation of all the [temporary files](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html) it uses.

Comment: very useful link, explained in simple words:)

What is that android_metadata table? During execution, when a perform: 

Select * from sqlite_master where type = 'table'

then i can see that table which i did not created. Where does it comes from and what is it's need? Thanks, Bunty

Comment: See [What is the android_metadata table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061868/what-is-the-android-metadata-table).