# Android's SQLiteDatabase: Failing to Open a Writeable Instance of a DB Because Could not setLocale()

Tags: android, sqlite

> `SQLiteOpenHelper.getWriteableDatabase()`

The error message I receive is:

> Failed to setLocale() when
>   constructing, closing the database

The only way I have found to get around it is to clear the application's data cache (i.e. delete all of it's database files) and start over. I would like to know a) Why this is happening and b) What can be done to avoid having to reset the application's data cache.

Comment: please tell me how you used SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS with SQLiteOpenHelper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got same problem, just found an solution for this problem at:
[No such table android_metadata, what's the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528489/no-such-table-android-metadata-whats-the-problem)