# Force close when a query the db

Tags: android

App uses an externally created database (using SQLitebrowser). Have code to copy database from assets folder to system location. App works fine in Emulator with Android 4.3, 4.2, 4.1. The App Force Close when I query database in Emulator with 3.0 and 2.3. 
When I go to DDMS view and check data->data->package->databases, I find only 1 file so I guess that the metadata is not created or generated.
I am not sure which part of the code is not supported in 3.0 and 2.3.
A code fragment:

```
Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                name=et1.getText().toString();
                Intent i=new Intent(v.getContext(),Display.class);
                i.putExtra("dname",name);
                i.putExtra("dr", r);
                i.putExtra("dn",n);
                startActivity(i);

                }
            });
```

LOGCAT:

```
11-29 00:13:18.897: D/dalvikvm(328): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 972 objects / 67008 bytes in 83ms
11-29 00:13:25.537: I/Database(328): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
11-29 00:13:25.537: E/Database(328): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.example.ast/databases/Astrology", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
11-29 00:13:25.677: I/Database(328): New database is being copied to device!
11-29 00:13:25.897: I/Database(328): New database has been copied to device!
11-29 00:13:25.917: I/Database(328): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: android_metadata
11-29 00:13:25.917: E/Database(328): SELECT locale FROM android_metadata failed
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328): Failed to setLocale() when constructing, closing the database
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: android_metadata
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:1950)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1818)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:817)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at com.example.ast.DataBaseHelper.checkDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:68)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at com.example.ast.DataBaseHelper.openDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:122)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at com.example.ast.Displayprediction.onCreate(Displayprediction.java:49)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-29 00:13:25.957: E/Database(328):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 00:13:25.957: I/Database(328): New database is being copied to device!
11-29 00:13:26.147: I/Database(328): New database has been copied to device!
11-29 00:13:26.147: D/AndroidRuntime(328): Shutting down VM
11-29 00:13:26.157: W/dalvikvm(328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ast/com.example.ast.Displayprediction}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.example.ast.DataBaseHelper.getrPred(DataBaseHelper.java:208)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at com.example.ast.Displayprediction.onCreate(Displayprediction.java:106)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-29 00:13:26.167: E/AndroidRuntime(328):  ... 11 more
11-29 00:13:30.357: I/Process(328): Sending signal. PID: 328 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Refer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647524/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have the problem:

```
sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: android_metadata
```

It means exactly what it say's:

```
no such table: android_metadata
```

Ok, now is a time for solution:
Android uses this table for handling some metadata of db i.e. version of database. If you created the database file on PC (or even on mac) there is no android specific tables. I prefer to create db from script on device and fill it with data (CSV files are extremely easy to load the data). It it's not possible - just create some db on the device, copy it from device to some db tool on you PC ad your own tables fill with data and use in the project.